# Silverlight | Correct way to do exception handling

Tags: silverlight, exception

Hello All,

I would like to know  how to handle the exception in the Silverlight
 ? Since it is the code which runs 
 at  Client side , So if some
 exception happens in the client nor related to web service . So should I show
 user friendly message and again make  a
 call to the server and store the exception  details there.

Is it the correct approach ? If not
 please  suggest a better one

Regards,

Phani

Answer (score 0):

The standard seems to be to expose a method in your webservice (such as logEvent(exception ex)) and handle it the same way you would any other .NET error.

[The Silverlight Integration Pack for Enterprise Library](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5Silverlight) apparently provides for a lot more support for error logging too, so that may be worth a look, though I haven't used it myself.